# Enable Transport TLS on postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, ssl, tls1.2

i'm trying to enforce transport level TLS on Postgres, requirement is that the server should force client to open a SSL connection, authenticate certs and also authenticate username/pass. below is my pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             postgres                                scram-sha-256
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
hostssl    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5 clientcert=1
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
#host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
#host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

and below is postgresql.conf

```
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = '/var/lib/pgsql/ssl/root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = '/var/lib/pgsql/ssl/server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#ssl_crl_dir = ''
ssl_key_file = '/var/lib/pgsql/ssl/server.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off
```

as soon as i provide `sslmode=require` flag in hba file and do

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql-14.service
```

below is the error i get

```
Job for postgresql-14.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql-14.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

this is the output of `journalctl -xe`

```
  [root@machine-name ]# systemctl status postgresql-14.service
● postgresql-14.service - PostgreSQL 14 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-05-17 14:26:24; 6s ago
     Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/static/
  Process: 21085 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-14/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 21079 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-14/bin/postgresql-14-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21085 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 17 14:26:24 machine-name systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 14 database server...
May 17 14:26:24 machine-name postmaster[21085]: 2023-05-17 14:26:24.558 PKT [21085] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
May 17 14:26:24 machine-name postmaster[21085]: 2023-05-17 14:26:24.558 PKT [21085] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
May 17 14:26:24 machine-name systemd[1]: postgresql-14.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 17 14:26:24 machine-name systemd[1]: postgresql-14.service: Killing process 21086 (postmaster) with signal SIGKILL.
May 17 14:26:24 machine-name systemd[1]: postgresql-14.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 17 14:26:24 machine-name systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 14 database server.
```

i'm using postgresql 14

Comment: So, what do you see in th PostgreSQL log?

Comment: nothing at all, logs don't show anything

Comment: What is your OS and version, and how did you install PostgreSQL on it?

Comment: Oracle Linux Server release 8.7, i'm not sure how postgresql was installed here as i was provided with it